# How to use group to represent a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

assume

> $\begin{align}
> –3x + 2y – 6z & = 6 \\ 
> 5x + 7y – 5z & = 6 \\ 
> x + 4y – 2z & = 8 \end{align}$

How to use group to represent this linear system of equation

Comment: Why do you expect there is a group that represents it? There is a nice matrix which represents it, but I don't see how you would represent it by a group in any way that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix

$$A:=\left(\begin{matrix}-3&2&-6\\5&7&-5\\1&4&-2\end{matrix}\right)$$

and the vectors $X:=\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right)$ and $B:=\left(\begin{matrix}6\\6\\8\end{matrix}\right)$. Then your system can be written as

$$AX=B.$$

If $A^{-1}$ exists then the set $G:=\{I,A^{n},:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ together with matrix multiplication is a group. In particular $$X=A^{-1}B.$$ But notice it is the knowledge of the existence of $A^{-1}$ what tells you $G$ is a group, and if you already know $A^{-1}$ exists then you can just solve the system $AX=B$. Moreover, it may happen $A^{-1}$ exists while the system still have **solutions**.

Also notice that the equation $AX=B$ is **not** an equation in the group; $B\notin G$.

Comment: does you mean that identity matrix is its group, A^n is also its group, (A^-1)*B is also its group?

Comment: if i want to find intersection of group of two linear system of equations, how can i choose which group to do the intersection?

Comment: @bolo: I have been thinking of what is your answer to Tobias comment? Thanks

Comment: How to know which group of this matrices belong to?